# How to setup add payment method like odesk using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, paypal, payment

I want to develop an application to setup a payment method like odesk works in contractor account and my coding language is asp.net.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty open-ended question, but I'm guessing that what you're after is a split payment..??

The [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) would be used for that, specifically [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

You've got options for using Parallel Payments or Chained Payments.  Depending on how you want things to flow you'll have to make that decision and adjust your API request accordingly.

PayPal provides an SDK for .NET that [you can get here](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#adaptive-payments).  It will allow you to setup the Pay request the way you need to.

You're going to need a sandbox account for testing purposes, and then you'll need to get your application approved by PayPal in order to obtain a live App ID (the app ID is a parameter that gets passed in the headers of Adaptive Payments API requests).

You do all of that through your [PayPal developer account](http://developer.paypal.com).